# Problem with commerce_checkout_page_info() function

Tags: commerce, hooks

I've been poking around in various forums trying to change the hard-coded values for the Checkout Page buttons and titles. For semantic reasons, I want to change the last submit button from 'Continue to next step' to 'Complete Submission'.

I have had success in changing the other buttons with combinations of hook_form_alter() and how hook_menu_alter()

```
function bartik_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
dpm($form_id);
dpm($form);
if (commerce_form_callback($form_id, $form_state) == "commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form"){
    $form['submit']['#attributes']['title'] = $form['submit']['#attributes']['value']=t("Add to Inquiry List");
    }
if(strpos($form_id, 'views_form_commerce_cart_form_default')===0){
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t("Update List");
    $form['actions']['checkout']['#value'] = t("Submit List");

    }
```

However, I am having problems changing the final submit button in the commerce_checkout_form_review form. I've tried the method suggested here http://mtt.desk.com/customer/portal/articles/1430204-how-to-customize-the-label-of-the-drupal-commerce-button-on-the-order-review-page, both as a module and as a function in the theme template, but neither method produces an error or gives me the desired text change.

```
function co_button_commerce_checkout_page_info_alter(&$checkout_pages) {
$checkout_pages['review']['submit_value'] = 'Submit Order';
}
```

So, I've been trying a couple of different variations, but I'm still not sure how to target the buttons on that form. I have also tried this little if statement, but it's still not effecting the change.

```
if(strpos($form_id, 'views_form_commerce_cart_form_default')===0){
$form['buttons']['continue']['#value'] = t('Complete submission');
}}
```

TIA, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I think this is the relevant portion of the array

```
buttons (Array, 4 elements)
#type (String, 8 characters ) fieldset
#attributes (Array, 1 element)
continue (Array, 6 elements)
#type (String, 6 characters ) submit
#value (String, 21 characters ) Continue to next step
#attributes (Array, 1 element)
#suffix (String, 59 characters ) <span class="checkout-processing element-      
#validate (Array, 1 element)
#submit (Array, 1 element)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can handle it with `hook_form_later`, try something like below,
change your condition according to your checkout base name ,
I hope this help you :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_values, $form_id) {
  if($form['checkout_pane']['#value']['base'] == 'checkout_pane_review') {
    $form['submit']['#value']='yourvalue';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since all you're doing is trying to change the button text, you really should just be altering the checkout page info array for the relevant checkout page so its "submit_value" reads as you want it to read. It looks like you got this right, and other folks can refer to the documentation in commerce_checkout.api.php for more information.

If you add this alter function to a module or theme that's already installed on the site, remember you need to clear the cache for the hook to register and actually start altering the array.

Comment: good to know I'm barking up the right tree, but I guess I'm not clear on exactly how the buttons are being targetted. At this point I know it's the commerce_checkout_form_review form, but I'm still not sure about how to pull the identifying info out of the $form variable array above.

Comment: turns out, I missed a curly brace, but it didn't trigger an error. thanks!

Comment: Hah, weird. Gotta love silent failures. : P